# Auto formatting a textbox text

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to auto format a text entered in a textbox like so:

If a user enters 2 characters, like 38, it automatically adds a space. so, if I type 384052
The end result will be: 38 30 52.

I tried doing that, but it's ofr some reason right to left and it's all screwed up.. what I'm doing wrong?

```
static int Count = 0;
     private void packetTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            Count++;
            if (Count % 2 == 0)
            {
                packetTextBox.Text += " ";
            }
        }


Thanks!
```

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Can you be more specific rather than just naming a control? I'm new to C#. I don't know the length, so I can't use a mask.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @user2714359: Sriram gave you a hint and he didn't posted an answer so copying hit hint into a searchbox and read a little should not to much effort for you.

Comment: Yes, @wonko79 is right. Am just giving a hint. may be you're looking for `MaskedTextBox` but doesn't know the name of it.

Comment: Looks like you need `n` number of characters without any limit but with single space each for two characters? What will you do when user deletes a character using `delete` or `backspace` ?

Comment: Assigning Text property of a TextBox causes cursor to be moved to position 0 in text, that's why it seems to be in reverse order. If you want to do it this way you should take care of that. It can be done manipulating selection in Text box (mainly SelectionStart property) but this approach is not error proof (for example you have to deal with user just pasting text into your textbox etc.)

Answer (score 1):

It's much nicer if you just let the user type and then modify the contents when the user leaves the `TextBox`.

You can do that by reacting not to the `KeyPress` event, but to the `TextChanged` event.

```
private void packetTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string oldValue = (sender as TextBox).Text.Trim();
    string newValue = "";

    // IF there are more than 2 characters in oldValue:
    //     Move 2 chars from oldValue to newValue, and add a space to newValue
    //     Remove the first 2 chars from oldValue
    // ELSE
    //     Just append oldValue to newValue
    //     Make oldValue empty
    // REPEAT as long as oldValue is not empty

    (sender as TextBox).Text = newValue;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

On TextChanged event:

```
 int space = 0;
 string finalString =""; 

 for (i = 0; i < txtbox.lenght; i++)
 {
       finalString  = finalString  + string[i];
       space++;
        if (space = 3 )
        {
            finalString  = finalString  + " ";
            space = 0;
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
    int amount;
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        amount++;
        if (amount == 2)
        {
            textBox1.Text += " ";
            textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0);
            amount = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. 
on TextChanged event

```
textBoxX3.Text = Convert.ToInt64(textBoxX3.Text.Replace(",", "")).ToString("N0");
textBoxX3.SelectionStart = textBoxX3.Text.Length + 1;
```